# getters on vuex not outputting what it should

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

i try to put the get request on store with vuex and the output doesn't appear, this are my state and getters code on store.js file:

```
  state:{
    timelines:[]

  }


 get_request:{
     timeReq: function(){
         this.$http.get('https://my-project-demo-71d7a.firebaseio.com/posts.json').then(function(data){


             return data.json();
         }).then(function(data){
             var blogsArray = [];

             for(let key in data){
                 data[key].id = key
                 blogsArray.push(data[key]);

             }
         state.timelines = blogsArray;
         });

     }
 },
 getters: {
     getTimeline: state =>{
         return state.timelines;
     }

 }
```

and this is my computed code to output it:

```
timeReq(){
 return this.$store.getters.getTimeline;
}
```

so, the problem is there's no error and none of it appeared on the result

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on from a non-testable code snippet. I'm attaching a [**link to a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/07hvwq2x/) you can mess around with and see if you can reproduce your issue there. It mimics an HTTP call.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        message: "loading..."
    },
    getters: {
        message (state) {
        return state.message;
      }
    },
    mutations: {
        init(state, payload){state.message = payload;}
    },
    actions: {
        init(context){
          setTimeout(
            function(){ 
                context.commit('init', 'message from the server'); 
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#example',
    computed: {
            message: {
            get() {
          return this.$store.getters.message
          }
        }
    }
})

store.dispatch("init");
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">
    <span>Message: {{ message }}</span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/vue@2.0.3,vuex@2.0.0"></script>
```